# Cross-Domain ajax to REST server with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm creating a mobile app using PhoneGap. So effectively I'm writing the app in jQuery Mobile, HTML and CSS.

Here's the problem: The server is a REST implementation. This means that to create a new 'entity' (e.g. user, car, hot babe), the server listens for POST requests. If the server will respond to GET requests by returning existing 'entities'.

How does one get the mobile app to send a POST request from jQuery? This sounds simple, but keep in mind that jQuery will change a jsonp datatype request to a GET, even if you specify POST. Also, keep in mind that the server and the app is not on the same domain, so this request is send cross domain, so setting the datatype to json will not work.

I have been stuck with this for 4 long hours. I can get it to work in the blink of an eye if I only care about GET requests, but getting a POST on the server has proven to be impossible so far.

Here is a simplification of the server-side code:

```
 class GatewayService extends Service[Request, Response] {
   def apply(request: Request) = {
     request.method -> Path(request.path) match {
       case GET -> Root / "car" => {
         println("---Get car---")
       }
       case POST -> Root / "car" => {
         println("---New car---")
       }
       case _ => {
         println("---Other method type ---")
      }
    }
}
```

And here's the jQuery code:

```
function serverRequest(formId, url) {
    var result = ""
    var formData = readFormData(formId);
    console.log("Submitting form:\n"+JSON.stringify(formData));

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
       dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            alert(response['message']);
            console.log("Received response: "+JSON.stringify(response));
            result = response;
         },
         error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
             console.log(
                 "The following error occured: "+ jqXHR,
                 textStatus, errorThrown
             );
         },
         complete: function(){
             //Nothing here for now
         }
    });
    return result;
}
```

If you have any ideas on getting a POST request cross domain with jQuery, please share your secret.

It appears that you cannot simply access a REST server directly from a mobile app developed on jQuery Mobile. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#introduction) instead of using JSONP? This should be supported by all modern browsers (and thus hopefully by phonegap too). This post relates to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8773095/773339

JSONP is limited to GET only.

Comment: EasyXDM is a great CORS implementation, works like a charm with PhoneGap. However, you need to be in control of the web service. http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll look into this. I'm still a little shocked that integration between a mobile device (using jQuery Mobile) and an existing REST server should be complex in any way.

Answer (score 0):

As you also know that, you cannot send a JSON or JSONP request as a POST request. A JSON or JSONP request is always a GET request. To get round this you can post to a page on your domain and then use this page to post the data. Like:

```
var data ="url=http://www.example.com/post_url.php&parameters=1&para=2";
 $.ajax({
  url: "your_domain_url",
  data: data,
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log('Success ' + data);
  },
  error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    console.log('Error ' + jqXHR);
  }
});
```

Get the post data in the file that exists in your domain and post it from there.
Hope that helps in some way.

Comment: It does provide some food for thought, thanks. It's not ideal though. I really thought that it should be extremely simple to access a REST service from a mobile, even one developed with jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap